# guzzle `http_errors` changes error from 500 to 404

Tags: php, phpunit, guzzle

i have a function im testing which suppose to return error 500 but after adding `'http_errors' => 'false'` to the `put` definition, the returned error changes from 500 to 404.
this is my function:

```
public function testApiAd_updateWithIllegalGroupId($adId) 
{
    $client = new Client(['base_uri' => self::$base_url]);
    try {
        $response = $client->put(self::$path.$adId, ['form_params' => [
          'name' => 'bellow content - guzzle testing',
          'description' => 'guzzle testing ad - demo',
          'group_id' => '999999999',
          ]]);
    } catch (Guzzle\Http\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {
        //Here i want to compare received error to 500
    }
}
```

right now this function will return `server error: 500` but it also stops the class from executing rest of the tests and i can't assert it. 
how can i use the guzzle `getStatusCode()` in my function while getting error 500 and not 404 as i mentioned above

Comment: in the catch block try `$e->getResponse()->getStatusCode()`

Comment: works perfectly! thank you very much!

Comment: Hi @Donoven you are welcome! I post as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BadResponseException contains the original Request and the Response object. So you can, the catch block the following assertion:

```
} catch (Guzzle\Http\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {
        //Here i want to compare received error to 500
        $responseCode = $e->getResponse()->getStatusCode();
        $this->assertEquals(500, $responseCode, "Server Error");
    }
```

Further info [in the doc](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html?highlight=badresponseexception#exceptions)